# Get active and inactive records from the table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have two tables like :

```
tbl student :

.................
id  | Name |Age |
.................
1   | A    |15  |
2   | B    |13  |
3   | C    |12  |
.................
```

Another table like Tbl_student_details :

```
.......................
id  | stud_id |section |
.......................
1   | 1       |A       |
2   | 1       |B       |
3   | 2       |C       |
.......................


Result Expected: 
Active student : count (2) because id 1 and 2 have records in student detail table
Inactive Student :count(1)  dont have any record in student detail table
```

What i need to get is i want active or inactive students ..

if any student have records in student_details then in need the count of these student and for inactive student
which student have no records in student details tablle i need a count of those student as well as for inactive student 
how can i get this active and inactive student can any one have any idea i need a query in laravel DB:: raw if not possible just suggest me query pleae help me related this ..

Comment: What would be the expected output as per your sample data ? Also, storing Age will not make any sense in long run, otherwise you will have to automatically keep on incrementing it every year

Comment: Use a left join on the inactive with `IS NULL Tbl_student_details.id` use a standard JOIN (INNER JOIN) for the others.

Comment: are you using laravel relationships?

Comment: Capt. Teemo  @ using DB:raw

Comment: in your models. do you have relationships?

Comment: Please see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 2):

- In order to consider all the students from the `student` table, you will need to use `Left Join`, so that even if there is no matching row in the `Tbl_student_details` table, you will still consider all the students.
- [`Count()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) function can be used count Inactive/Active students. `Count()` function does not count `NULL` values; so we can use [`Case .. When`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) expression to count Inactive students (`NULL` because of unmatching row).
- In order to count Unique number of Active students, we will need to use `Count(Distinct ..)` as you have duplicate rows for a `stud_id` in the `Tbl_student_details` table.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN tsd.id IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS Inactive_students, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT tsd.stud_id) AS Active_students 
FROM 
student AS ts 
LEFT JOIN 
  Tbl_student_details AS tsd ON tsd.stud_id = ts.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using left join and `CASE WHEN`

```
select 
   s.id,
   s.`Name`,
   s.`Age`, case when sd.stud_id is null then 'In Active' else 'Active' end as `StudentStatus`
from student s left join student_details sd 
on s.id=sd.stud_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupBy id's to get count of each id by left joining the student_details table with student table.

```
 DB::table('student')
                ->leftJoin('Tbl_student_details ', 'student.id', '=', 'Tbl_student_details .id')
                ->groupBy('student.id')->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using laravel you could setup your models for your tables

```
class Student extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'student';

    public function details()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\StudentDetails');
    }
}


class StudentDetails extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'student_details';

    public function student()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Student');
    }
}
```

And via query buider you can get count as

```
$students = App\Student::withCount('details')->get();
```

Above will return all students along with a property "details_count" which will give you the desired count from related table

[Counting Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships)

For Active/Inactive students you could write is as

```
$activeStudents = App\Student::has('details')->count();
$inActiveStudents = App\Student::doesntHave('details')->count();
```